# Installing CUnit on RHEL CUnit/CUnit.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux, gcc, rhel, cunit

I'm trying to set up CUnit for use on Red Hat Enterprise Linux. This is my test file in c:

```
#include <CUnit/CUnit.h>

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

At first, I was getting an error when using `gcc cunit-test.c -lcunit`:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcunit
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So I made a symlink so that `/usr/lib64/libcunit.so` points to `/usr/lib64/libcunit.so.1`, which fixed that error.

However, I'm still not able to use the CUnit files. When I compile my test file, with `gcc cunit-test.c -lcunit` I get the error

```
cunit-test.c:1:10: fatal error: CUnit/CUnit.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CUnit/CUnit.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: I bet you forgot to install the CUnit-devel package.

Comment: @Shawn I can't find CUnit-devel in the repositories, only CUnit (in x64_86 and i686 flavors) shows up. However, I can see the CUnit-devel package and others in https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/package-browser. Do you know why these packages aren't showing up on my machine?

Comment: Don't have the right repositories being used? Dunno, I don't use red hat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this question thanks to @Shawn.

To use CUnit, you need two packages: `CUnit`  and `CUnit-devel`. The `CUnit` package is in the default RHEL repositories, but the `CUnit-devel` package is in a repository called codeready-builder. To use CUnit on RHEl, you need to run `sudo subscription-manager repos --enable  codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms` (or rhel-9 if you are using RHEL 9, etc.) to enable the repository, then install the `CUnit-devel` package. Then you should be able to compile your program with `gcc cunit-test -lcunit`.

Comment: I had the same issue on Rocky Linux 9.3. I've added the epel-release by doing `sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb` ;  `dnf install epel-release` ; `sudo dnf install epel-release` ; `sudo dnf install CUnit-devel.x86_64`. This adds the epel-release as described here https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_quickstart.

Answer (score 0):

yum search CUnit，you will find two packages： CUnit-devel.x86_64 and CUnit.x86_64， choose that which contains header files and libraries

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).